# How to detect that the user has clicked outside of an mdl-layout__drawer and that the drawer has thus been closed?

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite

I'd like to be notified of the fact that the MDL drawer has been closed in order to be able to reload the main page based on some options that the user has set in the drawer.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `transitionend` event on the drawer element and then detect whether or not the drawer has the `is-visible` class to determine whether or not the drawer has just opened or closed. For example:

```
const drawer = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__drawer');
drawer.addEventListener('transitionend', (event) => {
  if (!drawer.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
    alert('closed');
  }
});
```